# Build Error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: git, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

A new Jenkins build is attempting to build off a feature branch in Bitbucket which is appendage of the main branch and that has exceeding a file-path-name threshold as indicated in the following error:

```
    error message:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3007,5): error : Copying file 
App_Config\Include\Serialization\Master\xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.Serialization.Master.Content.GlobalConfiguration.Release.config.disabled to 
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Config\Include\Serialization\Master\xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.Serialization.Master.Content.GlobalConfiguration.Release.config.disabled failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Seems to be a few people encountering a similar thing but no solution I have found is really helping.
The version of our software

- Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.8.28010.2048
- MSBuild version 14.0

Comment: Why do you use git tag?

Comment: How is that relevant?

Comment: It might be misleading...